# Attemping to translate the song "Alright"

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check

Given that some look like that don't understand the importance of macros [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVGGqzJ-g6g) is some reference by ScorpioMartinus where explains that speaking Latin without their macros is like speaking German without their umlauts, or Spanish without their accents.

The English lyrics of the song can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q-ChuY__ls). Can I please have feedback on the translation?

```
Sentiens ut sís solus
In hóc locó quó appellás domus
Sentiens ut nón sit locus ad proficiscendum
Sentiens ut nón possís aliquid esse

Sentiens ut habeás néminem plús [Not sure how translate this line]
Tot quod habes est paenitentia tua
Atque errorés tués et memoriae tuae
Sed quod nón vídes

Est quod eris sufficiens bonus
Nóli languére té

Nam es nón indignus [I may prefer using aestimo or axia with double negation, double negation must be perserved]
Némo est perfectus
Permané fortis manéque pugnam
Eris sufficiens bonus

Ergó sumé manum meam
Hoc nón est ipse fínis
Permané fortis manéque pugnam
Eris sufficiens bonus

Sentís ut sís assecutus
Turbine cruciatús
Máiore cónáris hat nullus pondus [Really not idea of how translate this line]
Simpleciter nón potes proficiscí

Simpleciter vís exíre
Vís rés tués sùmere íreque
Sed quod nón scis

Est quod eris sufficiens bonus
Nóli languére té

Nam es nón indignus
Némo est perfectus
Permané fortis manéque pugnam
Eris sufficiens bonus

Ergó sumé manum meam
Hoc nón est ipse fínis

Permané fortis manéque pugnam
Eris sufficiens bonus

Nón es gutta fenestrá
Sí langués pollicor recordábor

Nam es nón indignus
Némo est perfectus
Permané fortis manéque pugnam
Eris sufficiens bonus

Ergó sumé manum meum
Hoc nón est ipse fínis

Permané fortis manéque pugnam
Eris sufficiens bonus
Erit sufficiens bonus
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the importance of macros to us. Unfortunately I can't use them, IT Security told us to always disable macros.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say too much, really. As in your other question, what you've come up with largely represents an attempt at word-for-word vocabulary replacement rather than true translation, and therefore has all the limitations of that approach.

Still, I'll note just a couple of things of a more mechanical nature:

- The 4 occurrences of the participle *sentiens* have no syntactical connection to anything.
- *Quo dicis domus* would mean, if anything, either 'where you speak of houses' (though this would require a macron over the *u*) or 'where you, a house, speak.' Both *quo* and *domus* need to be accusative (singular) here.
- If I saw *locus ad proficiscendum*, I'd assume it's supposed to mean 'opportunity for setting out (on a journey)', not a way of rendering 'no where to run.' I don't think a gerund (or the verb *proficisci*) is what you want here. (I myself would probably say something like *locus ad quem* [or *locus quo*] *fugias* here.)
- *Assequocutus* is not a word (I think you mean *assecutus*).
- *Tues* is not a correct form of the possessive adjective.
- *Tace manum meam* would mean 'be silent about my hand,' not 'take my hand.'
- *Mane pugnam* would mean 'wait for the fight,' not 'keep the fight' (whatever *that* even means).
- *Languere* is intransitive, making *languere te* ungrammatical.
- The word is *simpliciter*, not *simpleciter*.
- You appear to be using *sufficiens* as an adverb, which it isn't.

Comment: (1) The original for Sentiens, Feeling, also does not make anysense.

Comment: (2) Quó appellás domus?, I am no sure how to do it neither.

Comment: (3) My dictionary has for trap assequor -cutus sum. 3 dep. tr.

Comment: (4) I am having problems with adjective declination.

Comment: (5) Tace? Upps.

Comment: (6) I am not using sufficiens as an abverb

Comment: Nóli diruere té is fine?

Comment: Also you neither checked the original, or you would note my error with the link or you already know the song, but not comment about the lines that I requested assistance.

Comment: @Elelphantus. In fact, I looked quite closely at the original – the link worked just fine when I clicked it.

Comment: It sended you to lyrics of still alive, and not of alright.

Comment: @Elephantus: No, when I clicked, it sent me to a youtube video page for 'Alright' with the lyrics in the description. Period. That's how I knew that, e.g., mane pugnam was meant to translate 'Keep the fight.'

Comment: That is because I mixed and by accident put the lyrics lyric in the macros reference link and you take the "incorrect" here.

Comment: Anyway, you still have not commented in the notes that put in the translation.

Comment: @Elephantus. No, nor will I. You'll find that people here are much more inclined to help if you're less openly hostile and argumentative, and show a bit more graciousness and gratitude for any assistance that they do offer, even if it doesn't cover every single part of your question.